# Restrict injection by namespace

Tags: structuremap

I have the following configuration:

```
For<ITranslatorProvider>().Singleton().Use<TranslatorProviderA>();
```

I have 3 translator providers: TranslatorProviderA, B and C.

Each one should be used under certain namespaces.

Project.Services > Use Provider A

Project.Site > User Provider B

...

Can I inject provider A, B or C depending from which namespace the request came?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it using [a convention](http://docs.structuremap.net/ScanningAssemblies.htm#section8). Something like this ought to work:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;
using StructureMap.Graph;
using StructureMap.TypeRules;

class TranslationConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if(!type.IsConcrete())
            return;
        var ctor = Constructor.GetGreediestConstructor(type);
        var translatorParameters= ctor.GetParameters()
            .Where(p => typeof(ITranslatorProvider)
            .IsAssignableFrom(p.ParameterType));
        if(!translatorParameters.Any())
            return;
        Type translatorType = GetTranslatorType(type);
        translationParameters.Aggregate(registry.For(type).Use(type), 
            (current, parameter) => 
                current.CtorDependency<ITranslatorProvider>(parameter.Name)
                .IsConcreteType(translatorType));
    }

    Type GetTranslatorType(Type type)
    {
        if(type.Namespace == "Project.Services")
            return typeof(TranslatorProviderA);
        if(type.Namespace == "Project.Site")
            return typeof(TranslatorProviderB);
        return typeof(TranslatorProviderC);

    }
}
```

The convention above only works for registering concrete types, so if you want the convention to bind the classes to some interface you need to change this part: `registry.For(type).Use(type)` into something more fitting. Have a look at the [built in conventions](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap/Graph/DefaultConventionScanner.cs) in StructureMap for some ideas.

You can use the convention in a scan:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(c => c.Scan(s =>    
    {
        s.TheCallingAssembly();
        s.Convention<TranslationConvention>();
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can inject provider based on namespace. But you can achieve the same thing (if I understand your implementation) by using named instances:

```
For<ITranslatorProvider>().Add<TranslatorProviderA>().Named("NS1");
For<ITranslatorProvider>().Add<TranslatorProviderB>().Named("NS2");
```

then use:

```
container.GetInstance<ITranslatorProvider>("NS1");
```